# When adding Service reference to a Silverlight 4 application ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file is generated empty

Tags: silverlight, wcf, service-reference

I've a WCF service hosted over SSL(https) whose web.config is like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="MyProject.HTMLService" behaviorConfiguration="HTMLServiceBehavior">
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="https://someip/HTMLService.svc"/>
<add baseAddress="https://hostname/HTMLService.svc"/>
</baseAddresses>
</host>
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="https" contract="MyProject.IHTMLService"/>

</service>
</services>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
<binding name="https">
<security mode="Transport"/>
</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HTMLServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

ClientAccessPolicy.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
  <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

When I try to add service reference into my silverlight 4 application, all the neccessary files are getting generated, but the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file contains only  tag. Also the configuration.svcinfo and configuration91.svcinfo files have no Bindinds, EndPoints and Behavior configuration.

How can this problem be resolved?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no support for webHttpBinding in any version pf SL

[More info and hints on a way to access a rest service from an SL application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470110%28VS.95%29.aspx)

No analog to the WebHttpBinding provided in WCF is provided. To access pure HTTP, REST, RSS/Atom, or AJAX services from Silverlight 3, use the techniques described in Accessing HTTP and REST-Based Services Directly, such as the WebClient class. To access ASP.NET AJAX services, see Accessing ASP.NET AJAX Services.